# Data scraping shopee

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to scrape prices from Shopee into googlesheets using the importxml function from  https://shopee.sg/Svelty-Pakkun-decomposition-yeast-120-Tablets-i.139075719.2136980675 but it gives me imported content is empty

tried copying the xpath but it didn work

importxml(https://shopee.sg/Svelty-Pakkun-decomposition-yeast-120-Tablets-i.139075719.2136980675, "//*div[@class='_3n5NQx']")

imported content is empty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

after disabling JavaScript for a given link you can see that page is empty which means that site is not possible to be scraped by Google Sheets. there are no workarounds. you will need to find yourself some other source.

[image: 0]